Gurobi: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing gurobipy: The specified module could not be found
I use 'conda' to install gurobi 11.0, and when I run the code on the pycharm 2023 platform 'from gurobipy import *'. It then always gives off '    from .gurobipy import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing gurobipy: The specified module could not be found.'
I have tried several methods found online but failed again and again. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thank you so much!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Most likely, PyCharm uses a different Python environment than what you had activated when installing gurobipy. You can try running the installation from within a PyCharm terminal instead.
